# CSS layout issue with 2 columns

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am facing layout issue with styling of a page and not able to get any clue for that.

Page is at 
http://testenv.pagalhost.com/gobuzzinga/profile.php?profile=Abhishek+Srivastava-2

Issue is when we load this page at the bottom there are 2 sections , one which shows images uploaded by user and other shows its followers list but they are not getting aligned properly even when width and float elements in CSS are correct.

Again when we change the tab to activities its getting aligned with div at the left.

Best part is when I am coming back to first tab , Uploads its aligned properly.

```
<script>
fetchUserDetails('getProfile');
fetchUserDetails('getAlbum');
fetchUserDetails('getActivityCount');
fetchUserDetails('getFollowers');
</script>
```

This is where a function is called and data is fetched when page is loading.

My fetchuserDetails is as

```
function fetchUserDetails(type)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processes/userAction.php",
      cache: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 'action='+type+'&userInfo=<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['profile']))?$_REQUEST['profile']:"current"; ?>&page='+1,
      success: function(html){
        if(type=='getProfile')
          displayProfile(html)
        else if(type=='getFollowers')
          displayFollowers(html)
        else if(type=='getFollowing')
          displayFollowing(html)
        else if(type=='getAlbum')
          displayAlbum(html)
        else if(type=='getActivityCount')
          displayActivityCount(html)
      }
    });              
  }
```

My Display Followers Function is :

```
function displayFollowers(data)
  {
    htmlData = '';
    var count = 1;
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
     htmlData += '<div>Following/Followers</div><div class="twitter-wrapper"><div class="twitter-widget"><div class="user-info">';
     htmlData += '<img src="'+val.pic+'" alt="avatar" style="height:50px;widht:auto;" />';
     htmlData += '<p>'+val.name+'</p>';
     htmlData += '<span>'+val.current_location+'</span>';
     htmlData += '</div>';
     htmlData += '<div class="stats">';
     htmlData += '<p><span>2,3k</span>posts</p>';
     htmlData += '<p><span>326</span>following</p>';
     htmlData += '<p><span>752</span>followers</p>';
     htmlData += '</div>';
     htmlData += '<span>'+count+'</span>';
     htmlData += '<div class="corner"></div></div>';
     htmlData += '<div class="compose-card">';
     htmlData += "<div class='userFollow' id='follow"+data.u_id+"'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='follow follow_no' id='"+data.u_id+"'>Follow</a></div>";
     htmlData += "<div class='userFollow' id='remove"+data.u_id+"' style='display:none'><a href='#' class='remove follow_yes' id='"+data.u_id+"'>Following</a></div>";
     htmlData += '</div></div>';
     count++;
   });

    $('#followersList').append(htmlData);

    bindFollowFunctions();
  }
```

And display album function is :

```
function displayAlbum(data)
  {
    var htmlData = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
     htmlData += '<a href="'+val.pic+'" ><img src="'+val.pic+'" /></a>';
    });

    $('.albumSet').html('');
    $('.albumSet').append(htmlData);
    $(function() {
      $(".albumSet img").unveil(300);
    });

    $('.albumSet').each(function() { 
      $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', 
        type: 'image',
        gallery:{enabled:true},
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
      });
    }); 
  }
```

I am not getting any clue of this layout issue , can someone please point out the issue as what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have given `display: none` to child `div`. That is by adding "hidden" class to child `div` of  `#content_tabActivities` and `#content_tabFollowers`.

When page loads `#content_tabActivities` and `#content_tabFollowers` are not hidden.
But when you click on the tabs, `display: none` is added to these div's.

Solution :

give "hidden" class to  `#content_tabActivities` and `#content_tabFollowers`

or

Wrap `#content_tabUploads`, `#content_tabActivities` and `#content_tabFollowers` 
into a `div` and give them `width: 690px;` and `float:left`